# What does "save (one) the trip" mean?

Tags: meaning

A woman says to Armand:

> Woman: How nice of you to **save me the trip** to that place.
> Doctor sent me to tell you he can see you tomorrow morning.

What does "save (one) the trip" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The woman didn't have to take a trip to that place because of the action of the person she is speaking to.
He saved her from having to make that trip.